# Firebase cloud messaging server key showing disabled

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to push a new android application to the play store. when I tried to add a new app to my one signal account it asked me for a firebase server key and a sender id. So I went firebase - settings - project settings - cloud messaging from here I got my sender id but the server key is disabled.
This is the error it's showing
Cloud Messaging API (Legacy)  Disabled
If you are newly integrating messaging into your app, use the latest Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1). If you are an existing user of Cloud Messaging API (Legacy), consider migrating to the latest Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1). What should I do to get a firebase server key?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the server key of Cloud Messaging API (Legacy) is the only way at this moment.
I also came across on this issue recently and felt very confused on the term `Server key` as the new API didnt offer such key.

I came across the issue in Azure Notification Hubs.
Please check the following issue to see any follow up
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/95498

Answer (score 0):

By Default You will se the Cloud Messaging API (Legacy) as disabled , but if you still want to get the server key , According One Signal's Documentation
You have to manually enable it from the google cloud console , you can Refer This

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/generate-a-google-server-api-key#step-2-get-your-firebase-cloud-messaging-token-and-sender-id

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).